# How to Stop EC2 instances automatically without specific tag and value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, tags

In AWS, All the instances which do not have the tag "os" with value "linux" should shut down in the region ?.

can someone please help doing this. I tried, but not able to achieve.

I found the possibility to stop instances with specific tag, but unable to create lambda function to stop ec2 instances with out specific tag and value.

Comment: You should get a list of _all_ instances, then filter out the desired instances within your AWS Lambda function code.

Answer (score 1):

Could you get a list of all of your instances, then iterate through them, declining to terminate if they have the tag? In Python, something like:

```py
import boto3

def has_tag(instance):
   # check if instance has tag

client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_instances(
    Filters=[
        ...
    ],
    ...
)

for instance in response['Reservations']['Instances']:
    if not has_tag(instance):
        #terminate instance
```

Comment: Dear James Shapiro, there are like 100 instances in single region, its not possible to collect and filter. Is there any possible way to terminate instances without filtering

Comment: Hi Arun, would using multiple calls with NextToken to list all of the EC2 instances not solve this problem? See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Resource Group Tagging API to get the list of resource that do not have that value.

This would get you a list of the ARN of all the EC2 instances that do not have "linux" as the value of any tag:

`` aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters ec2:instance --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[?!(Tags[?Value==`linux`])].ResourceARN' ``

Assuming "linux" is a value *only* used for the "os" tag to filter out any resources whose tags do not have that value, but you can adjust the JMESPath query as needed.